# How to find connectivity of rows through common elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to find if remaining rows of a matrix are connected with the first row. For example, I have a matrix as below:

1 2 5 9
2 1 4 3
4 3 6 7
8 9 6 3

In this matrix, row 2 is connected to row 1 because of common elements 1 and 2. Row 3 is connected to row 2 (common elements 3 and 4), so it is also connected to row 1. Likewise, row 4 is connected to row 1 because it is linked to row 2 and row 3 through element 3. Finally, I can say that row 1 is connected to all the remaining rows in the given matrix.

How can I do that in Matlab without using loops? It will be a bottleneck for a very large matrix of thousands rows in my code.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Is there any bound on the values the array elements can take? Here you've only got values 1..9, but I assume that's just an example.

Comment: No, there is no bound, and all elements are integer.

Comment: I think you are looking at permutations of your rows and then a intersect to see if there are common elements

Comment: @GameOfThrows I don't think you have to look at permutations, just runs of connected rows. If row 1 is not connected to row 2, then row 3 cannot be connected to row 1. ruby, How fast does this need to be? I can't figure out how to do it without loops, but on a 1000x200 test matrix it takes (to me at least) a negligible amount of time.

Comment: Usually my  matrix is 10000x20 in size. Ideally, the elapsed time should be less than 0.5s because the connectivity search is performed in every time step.

Comment: Hm... I'm running about 2.5s for a matrix that size, although I'm sure that the fact I'm on Octave slows it down just a bit. I'll keep thinking.

Comment: You said `remaining rows`. What do you mean?  As an example. If row 3 is connected to row 5 and row 5 to row 1, when you arrive to row 3 you won't see it's connected to 1. But once you arrive to row 5 then row 3 is no longer a `remaining row` (since it has already been checked). So in this case should row 3 be reevaluated?

Comment: is there a chance that there are different groups connected? like (1,3) is a group and (2,4) is a group? or is it just those rows are connected and the rest is not?